# Calculate the everyday difference between the highest and lowest price

Tags: mql4, mql5

I have a simple task:
Calculate the daily difference between highest price and lowest difference and print the result in the console.

So far I can only successfully do:

```
void OnTick()
  {
//---
   SymbolInfoTick("EURUSD", tickInfo);
   Print(tickInfo.last);
  }
```

Can anybody give a sample code for this simple task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this abstract sql query
"select subract(Max_price, Min_price) from table_name group by date" if you are using database.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I mean mql, not sql.